# Robot Framework and CI, run in container or not

Tags: testing, jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, robotframework

What is the best practice to setup a Robot Framework project, and integrate it as a part of continuous integration pipeline (Jenkins), when developing containerized microservices?

Is it OK to install Robot Framework on Jenkins slave, or is it better practice to run Robot Framework inside a container running on the slave, possibly restarting the container and mounting the test data for each build?

How to organize Robot Framework projects? Should acceptance tests for user interface be included on the same repository, or as an independent project? Latter would seem more modular, as user interface may be dependent of various backing services, and it's easier to coordinate the phase of testing as a last job if more services are added, when it is an independent project. But what is the best practice and why?

Where I can find complete tutorial to explain a viable pattern for TDD with containerized microservices?